# How do I preserve state of a gridview between postbacks?

Tags: gridview, session-state

I have a gridview that is populated by drop down lists. I change the text in the cell to the chosen item in the list. When I make a second choice the first one is erased. Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the EnableViewState = true?
Also are you doing the initial databind on the IsPostBack === true of the page_load?  I.E. You are not rebinding it on EVERY postback...